# Ajax posting and uppercase special character's encoding

Tags: php, ajax, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I am posting the serialized contents of a form with jQuery AJAX, and it works fine except for uppercase special characters, such as Ñ or Ö.

Using the test string `aÑejÖs` I post it using a simple:

`$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/target.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: data
})`

and I get `a�ej�s` back. Every time. It works just fine with the same characters in lowercase (`ñ, ö`).

I have checked the encodings of everything and it's all utf-8, I've also tried urlencoding, using html entities and manually setting the post encoding (to UTF-8 and ISO8859-1).

I've also tried several things on the receiving side such as iconv, utf8_encode, utf8_decode, mb_convert_encoding, and probably some others.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this on the JS side by skipping the serialize and encoding the string twice:

`$(this).find('textarea, input').each(function(a, b) {
    data +=  $(this).attr('name') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent($(this).val())) + '&';
});`

This way I get a URLencoded string I can work with in PHP.